# Ruby on Rails: strange voting increment behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have an up and a downvote button that inserts a vote with a value of 1 or -1 into the database. This works correctly. Then, I display the total vote count for that element by summing up its votes' values. However, this isn't working correctly, because the vote sum display is acting really strange:

The first vote on a video doesn't seem to increment it at all. Then the second vote does. If I go from an upvote to a downvote, it increments up once, and then the next downvote is down. This is difficult to explain, but maybe you can figure out what is wrong with my code.

I have this function in my Video model (the element that is voted on, it has_many video_votes):

```
def vote_sum
  read_attribute(:vote_sum) || video_votes.sum(:value)
end
```

I also have this in my VideoVote model:

```
after_create :update_vote_sum

private

  def update_vote_sum
    video.update_attributes(:vote_sum => video.vote_sum + value)
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `update_attributes!` (with `!`) ? Any errors from that? Also `update_attributes` does validations - could a validation be interfering? Also, do you know of the [`increment`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations) method? Where is `value` coming from in `update_vote_sum` ?

Comment: value is coming from my controller where I set it equal to either 1 or -1. That part works fine. It's also a column in my video_votes table and is stored in there.

Comment: `update_attributes!` doesn't seem to make any difference in the behavior of `vote_sum`

Comment: validations aren't interfering, I haven't really set up any of them yet

Comment: How is it that your checking whether the vote worked or not? Directly querying the SQL database using SELECT or via some Rails object/calls?

Comment: By just observing the vote_sum that I render in my view when I press the up/downvote buttons... I have it update the vote display with ajax currently.

Comment: The votes work... I see them being inserted into the database in my logs. It's the way that I'm arriving at and updating the vote_sum that must be faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing all the code but I would try changing `vote_sum`

```
def vote_sum
  video_votes.sum(:value)
end
```

...to see if the association is working fine. That way you've narrowed the issue down to being the Video object's `vote_sum` cache column.

You could also try the following instead of overidding the vote_sum attribute in case that's causing issues:

```
def total_vote_sum
  vote_sum || video_votes.sum(:value)
end
```

I'm assuming the controller / view / js logic is all correct. Classic case for test driven development using a tool like Cucumber, but that's a whole other discussion lol.

Comment: It works with your first example, so it's something with the Video object's vote_sum cache column/

Comment: I liked having the cache though :/ the votes updated so quickly. Have any ideas on how I could get the cache column to work?

Comment: If you query the database directly, does the cache column match the value found in `video_votes.sum(:value)` (ie. is the after_create callback working as expected) ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to figure that out... how do I query the db directly, and how do I check the value of video_votes.sum(:value)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'm pretty confident that there's something wrong with `def vote_sum` that's preventing the cache from updating correctly